# How can I make some tile map unmovable in unity2d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new for Unity, I got a tile map like below, and I want those tiles (**in red box**) **unmovable**, but I have no idea how to implement it. Is anyone can help me?
Thanks for your help :)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what im guessing (because the question is quite unclear) u are talking about tilemap layers.
U want ur player to walk on the street instead of the buildings.

u should have one tilemap in your grid as seen in the picture below, if u add more tilemaps and change the "Order in layer" to a higher number it will layer on top of the tilemap, that way u can put a tilemap collider on the street and no collider on the background and your character will walk onthe street.

[image: Tilemap order layer image]

Comment: thank you! I will try it. And I'm sorry my English is suck.haha.